# Using Quick Sort in C to sort in reverse direction (descending)?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures

To sort I call `qsort(myArray,100,sizeof(int), comp)`

```
int comp(const int * a, const int * b)
if(a==b)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    if(a<b)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

First,
This doesn't really work, when I sort an array `(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1),` I get `(4,8,7,6,5,9,3,2,1)` - NOT really sorted.

Second,
How would I sort in the other direction? Is there a special flag for qsort I need to pass?

Answer (score 11):

You need to compare the values, not their addresses. Try

```
int comp(const int * a, const int * b)
{
 return *a - *b;
}
```

To reverse the ordering, use

```
int comp(const int * a, const int * b)
{
 return *b - *a;
}
```

Comment: You should not use subtraction as a "shortcut" for comparisons since it will easily overflow/underflow when the values are far enough apart (e.g. comparing INT_MAX to -1, etc.).

Comment: If you want a fancy one-liner comparison that *works*, you can do `return (*a > *b) - (*b > *a);`

Comment: @caf: I think `return (*a > *b) ? 1 : ((*a < *b) ? -1 : 0);` would be safer since you don't have to rely on whatever `int` value is returned for the comparison being in range.

Comment: @bobbymcr: The comparison operators always return either `1` or `0`.

Comment: @caf: I see... you are right, the standard says so. (C99 standard, 6.5.8.6)

Answer (score 7):

Change your compare function so that it is ordering the way you like.

And the compare function takes pointers to compared data (not the data itself). Eg.

```
int compare (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{ 
   int i1 = *(int*) p1;
   int i2 = *(int*) p2;
   if (i1 < i2) return -1;
   else if (i1 == i2) return 0;
   else return 1;
   /* or simply: return i1 - i2; */
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have an example of a compare function that actually works? I am not really sure how to set the compare function up? Also I thought mine worked, but it returns an array that is...less ordered than the original haha

Comment: Did you test my compare function? I'm quite sure it should work. Read more then man page of qsort. http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

Comment: I still get the same ordering 4,8,7,6,5,9,3,2,1,1

Comment: Might be the way I cam calling it? qsort(ar,10,sizeof(int),comp)

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator is broken.  You are comparing the pointer values rather than the values being pointed to.  Add the `*` dereference operator to the `a` and `b` comparisons and it should work.