# How do I use qsort() but in decreasing order?

Tags: c

```c
void sort_array(void)
{
    int sorted_arr[arr_count];

    qsort(sorted_arr, arr_count, sizeof(*sorted_arr), compare_qsort);
    return;
}
```

I can't figure out how to use qsort in reverse can anyone help me?

Comment: `int compare_qsort_inverted(const void *a, const void *b) { return -compare_qsort(a, b); }` and in your function use this new sorting function: `qsort(..., compare_qsort_inverted);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be how I would solve it:

```c
int compare_qsort(const void *pointer1, const void *pointer2)
{
    //Returns a sorted array in descending order.
    const int *pointeri = pointer1;
    const int *pointerj = pointer2;
    return *pointerj - *pointeri;
}
```

Notice how you flip it so that the `pointerj` variable is subtracting the `pointeri` variable.

I found this other question that you could refer to: [Using Quick Sort in C to sort in reverse direction (descending)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115624/using-quick-sort-in-c-to-sort-in-reverse-direction-descending)

Comment: sorry  I just wanted to see what it did...